# Android programmatically change drawableRight

Tags: android, drawable, android-drawable

How I can change programmatically drawableRight image ?

This is my Button with the drawableRight, Already set with drawableRight image -

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#496a4a"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_add_white_24px"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:text="Shop"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button2" />
```

And here I wont to change the drawableRight image -

```
public void onClick(View v){
    if(v.getId()==R.id.button){
        //Log.d(TAG,"button");
        // Need to change the drawableRight image !
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.drawableRight, 0);
```